# HTML document requires refreshing to show CSS

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

I'm using Adobe Dreamweaver CS6 to make a simple HTML/CSS web page but for some reason the document is not displaying the CSS correctly. However, if you refresh the page a few times (No Changes ), the CSS will take effect. Is this a Dreamweaver problem or an issue with my code (below) and how do you fix it?

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
.menu{
 width:1600px;
 background-color:FCEE21;
 position:fixed;
 top:0px;
 left:-5px;
 height:75px;
 }
.logo{
 background-image:url(Pictures/Logo.png);
 position:fixed;
 top:0px;
 left:5px;
 background-size:75px 75px;
 width:75px;
 height:75px;
 cursor:pointer;
 }
 
 .menu-list{
  position:fixed;
  left:300px;
  list-style-type:none;
  font-family:"Adobe Heiti Std R";
  }
.logo:hover{
 background-image:url(Pictures/Logo--Hover.png);
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<title>Leuven Wang | Amateur Web Designer</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="menu">
<div class="logo"></div>
<ul class="menu-list">
<li>PORTFOLIO</li>
<li>SERVICES</li>
<li>CONTACT</li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use a browser to text your page, if the changes have not gone through you need to do a "hard" refresh (CTRL + F5). What is happening is the browser is caching the CSS file so it does not have to keep re-downloading it. Hard refresh will force the browser to get the new updated file.

Comment: Your code looks OK. It may happen due cache pages. Have you tried ctrl+refresh? It will remove all the cache.

Comment: your css path is ok? include css in any directory.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a caching issue. When you visit a webpage it will keep a copy of the requested files on your computer in order to speed up the load time of the webpage the next time you load it. This is because it is quicker to load a css file from your computer than it is to download it from the Internet.

The common way to clear your cache for a webpage is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>. This will force your computer to refresh the current page, ignoring any cached files, allowing your CSS changes to be seen.

#### Edit

If you use Chrome (I don't know if this feature is available in other browsers), you can press <kbd>F12</kbd> to load up the Developer Tools. Click on the small cog that appears in the top-right of this new window and an options screen will open. There will be an option called 'Disable cache (while DevTools is open). Tick this and click on the little 'x' on the options screen. As long as the Developer Tools panel is open, the browser will not cache the css file.

Comment: Every time I press CTRL and F5 it reloads with the CSS but afterwards it still doesn't work all the time with just F5. Is there any permanent fix?

Comment: Some browsers, such as Chrome or Firefox, will let you install plugins. You could try searching for a 'cache killer' plugin?

Comment: If you use Chrome (I don't know if this feature is available in other browsers), you can press <kbd>F12</kbd> to load up the Developer Tools. Click on the small cog that appears in the top-right of this new window and an options screen will open. There will be an option called 'Disable cache (while DevTools is open). Tick this and click on the little 'x' on the options screen. As long as the Developer Tools panel is open, the browser will not cache the css file.

Comment: If you use Safari, hard refresh by shift-clicking the browser's refresh button. If you're on a Mac and use FF or Chrome, it's shift-command-R. There's a more complete list of browsers' hard refresh commands at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Bypass_your_cache#Bypassing_cache